# How do I add gRPC as a dependency in OMNet++/Eclipse CDT (Linux)?

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker, grpc, omnet++

What I have done:

- I cloned and built grpc from the source by following the instructions
- I have added library path to my project as *path_to_clone*/bazel-bin

I keep getting a lot of errors looking similar to
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/*path_to_library* undefined reference to grpc_*package*

What I want to achieve:
Link grpc to my project.